# The constructor GeoPoint(double, double) is undefined. What's wrong with that?

Tags: android

I am having error: "The constructor GeoPoint(double, double) is undefined". Why is it so? How to do it right? As I understand there are all necessary libraries linked and syntax seems to be right.

```
package com.fewpeople.geoplanner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class GeoplannerActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final MapView mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

     MapController mMapController = mMapView.getController();

     double x, y;
     x= 60.113337;
     y= 55.151317;

     mMapController.animateTo(new GeoPoint(x, y));

     mMapController.setZoom(15);

    }

    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GeoPoint takes two integers that are coords in microdegrees.  I use this method for simplicity:

```
/**
 * Converts a pair of coordinates to a GeoPoint
 * 
 * @param coords double containing latitude and longitude
 * @return GeoPoint for the same coords
 */
public static GeoPoint coordinatesToGeoPoint(double[] coords) {
    if (coords.length > 2) {
        return null;
    }
    if (coords[0] == Double.NaN || coords[1] == Double.NaN) {
        return null;
    }
    final int latitude = (int) (coords[0] * 1E6);
    final int longitude = (int) (coords[1] * 1E6);
    return new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
}
```

Also, your Activity should extend MapActivity.

Answer (score 2):

Tided up Ian G. Clifton's nice utility method which seemed unnecessarily verbose:

```
/**
 * Converts a pair of coordinates to a GeoPoint
 * 
 * @param lat double containing latitude
 * @param lng double containing longitude
 *            
 * @return GeoPoint for the same coords
 */
public static GeoPoint coordinatesToGeoPoint(double lat, double lgn) {
    return new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lgn * 1E6));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

java does not automatically cast double to int (loss of data and such), and the only constructor for GeoPoint accepts 2 ints. So write:

```
mMapController.animateTo(new GeoPoint((int)x, (int)y));
```

Or declare your points as ints in the first place.

Comment: Replaced. Have got new error "The method animateTo(GeoPoint, Message) in the type MapController is not applicable for the arguments (int, 
 int)" . Why?

Comment: I would go from Ian's comment. It was more complete.