# can't reocgnize ParseGeoPoint

Tags: android, parse-platform, geopoints

I am trying to retrieve a `parseGeoPoint` for a certain record like this:

```
ParseGeoPoint myCoordinates = shopInfo.getParseGeoPoint("coordinates");
```

but I am getting this error: `can't recognize 'getParseGeoPoint(String)'`

I checked their [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#getParseGeoPoint(java.lang.String)) and getParseGeoPoint is a valaid method, how can I fix this?

Comment: not sure but it might require (Double)  rather than string, usually geopoints are in (Double) format

Comment: Actually is microdegrees -- have a look here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960542/the-constructor-geopointdouble-double-is-undefined-whats-wrong-with-that

Comment: the string is a key that refers to a double value in the database

Comment: Have a look the above comment, it looks like it takes in microdegress, converting the double to microdegress should work

Comment: guys this is for custom geoPoint that is used with Parse.com not the one used with google maps